# C++ new thread sleeps main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

Running the following code:

```
methodOne(){
    std::thread t(&ChatBubble::runChatBubbleThread, this);
    t.join();
}
```

runChatBubbleThread:

```
runChatBubbleThread(){
    // code here
    sleep(2000);
    // more code here    
}
```

My understanding is that the new threat `t` is created, executes its code and then joins the main thread once it has completed, is there a reason `sleep()` is sleeping the main thread?

Only thing I can think of is that `t.join` is waiting for the thread to complete before it continues on main thread, but then whats the point of threading if it has to wait!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of `thread.join` is to block until the thread is dead. If you want to do something in your main thread before waiting on your new thread, do it before you `join`.

Comment: Alternately, if you never want to wait for it, call `t.detach()`

Comment: Detached threads are nasty beasts when it comes to their local variables and the way they interact with static objects.

Comment: @ChrisDodd thanks for this,  i have tried the detach method, but it generates a `Access violation executing location` error

Comment: @SergeyA: having static objects refer to local variables is a problem no matter how you slice it -- threads just make it worse.  You only detach from a thread if *never* want to wait for it, including on program exit (which will just summarily kill the thread without giving an opportunity to clean up, so you have to make sure the thread needs no cleanup).

Comment: @ChrisDodd, not sure if I made myself clear enough. It is not that static objects refering to local variables. It is the fact that detached thread will be killed after main thread. And all the static objects of the main thread would be destructed by the time. So any attempt to use them will result in undefined behaviour, aka coredump. And the attempt will take place sooner or later. I dealed with my share of 'exit coredumps', happening right before program exits.

Answer (score 1):

A few easy ways to do this.

jwde covers the first

```
void methodOne(){
    std::thread t(&ChatBubble::runChatBubbleThread, this);
    // do other stuff that needs to be done here.
    t.join(); // wait for thread to finish before returning in case thread
              // is not done
}
```

And John C chimed in with the second while I was typing this.

```
void methodTwo(){
    std::thread t(&ChatBubble::runChatBubbleThread, this);
    t.detach(); // let thread run to completion on it's own time
}
```

But a warning on detach. If main exits before the thread finishes... You're gonna have a bad day. You probably want to keep tabs on the threads you have running to make sure they finish before you exit the program.

So method three:

```
void methodThree(std::vector<std::thread> & threads){
    threads.emplace_back(&ChatBubble::runChatBubbleThread, this);
}
```

and at the bottom of main

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    ...

    object.methodThree(threads);

    ...

    for (std::thread &t: threads)
    {   
        t.join();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Editing to add this won't scale well over time. Threads will build up in the vector even though they have ceased, so running a cleaner from time to time to detect, remove and dispose of completed threads is required.

Edit 2: Missed the & to get a reference. Can't copy threads for a number of really good reasons.

Edit 2B. Yes. This will jam on a hung thread. I'd like to say that never happens in MY code, but look up a couple lines.

Usually my thread's execution loop will look something like this:

```
while (!terminated)
{
    // do stuff, but no blocking operations without a timeout.
}
```

If that still hangs, out comes the debugger. I have to say I don't have a good out for this case short of wrapping the loop with a bomb on a timer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Number three looks like a good option, on using `detach` i had memory errors, which is what I assume you are referring to here. Only problem on method three is `for (std::thread t: threads)` is run in the main game loop for the GUI but on `threads` the error saying `std::thread::thread cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function`

Comment: @IGarratt I probably missed something stupid. Let me write and build this to see what. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: `std::thread` objects are not copyable, so you need `for (std::thread &t : threads)` if you want to loop over the threads.

Comment: The main problem with method 3 is that its easy to get a hang on exit, if one of threads is waiting for some event that will never happen now that the program is (trying to) exit...

Comment: Durrrr.... Knew I couldn't copy the suckers. Didn't notice the lack of reference. Was about to flip over to old school iterators.

Answer (score 0):

The thread is running as soon as you construct it.

`t.join` does in fact wait for thread t to complete. It doesn't have to wait; you don't have to call `join`. `join` is to synchronize the threads; sometimes you want main to wait (usually, arguably always, not right away, but after doing a few other tasks that you want to be in parallel). "The function returns when the thread execution has completed." [Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/join/)

On the other hand, you can use `detach` which "Detaches the thread represented by the object from the calling thread, allowing them to execute independently from each other." [Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/detach/). You should call `detach` before the thread's destructor would be called.